# Lua table sort does not work

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I have the below program code which tries to sort a given list. I have tried various options and it still doesn`t work.

```
local List = {}    
List[143] = "143"    
List[145] = "145"    
List[120] = "120"       
List[178] = "178"   
table.sort(List, compare)
```

compare function is defined as

```
function compare(a, b)    
    if tonumber(a) < tonumber(b) then    
        return true    
    end
end
```

Above table.sort does not work to any order. I just want to sort it to increasing numerical order. If you have any ideas about this please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: your example is sorted already, do you expect the keys or the values sorted? + see http://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html

Comment: Your compare function could be simplified to just `return tonumber(a) < tonumber(b)`.

Comment: Sorting means to reorder values referenced by a ordered set of keys. Which keys do you intend to use? Or, more specifically, what is the outcome that you expect in your example?

Answer (score 12):

[`table.sort`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) (and much of the rest of the [`table.*`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.5) functions) is defined only for operations on array-like tables. That means tables with contiguous integer keys from `1..n`. Your table doesn't meet those criteria.

Answer (score 3):

The keys of that table do not satisfy requirements of that function. The keys must start at 1 and sequentially increase to N, as per [Lua ref manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) ("Sorts table elements in a given order, in-place, from `table[1]` to `table[n]`"). Try

```
local List = {}
List[1] = "143"    
List[2] = "145"    
List[3] = "120"       
List[4] = "178"   
table.sort(List, compare)
```

or even better

```
local List = {"143", "145", "120", "178"}
table.sort(List, compare)
```

Answer (score 0):

Key-value pairs in a table don't have a stable order.  For each run through with the `pairs` or `next` functions, you may see a different sequence of key-value pairs. (Presumably the sequence might change as a result of adding or removing from the table.)

Except for setting or getting at specific keys, other table operations use the positive integer keys. <strike>`maxn` gets the maximum key n that does not have a nil value.</strike> The others assume the keys are contiguous. For such tables, the positive integer keys can be considered to have a definite range and are ordered so sorting would make sense.

The positive integer keys in `List` are not contiguous. So, `sort`'s behavior is not useful (and, in general, non-deterministic).

Perhaps, you wanted something like this operation over all positive integer keys:

```
local values = {}
-- extract values from positive integer keys
for key, value in pairs(List)
    if (type(key) = "number") and key > 0 then
        table.insert(values, value)
        List[key] = nil    
    end
end
-- sort and restore them to the table
table.sort(values, function(a,b) return tonumber(a)<tonumber(b) end)
for key, value in values
    List[key] = value
end
```

Comment: That isn't modern Lua... it would have to read `for key,value in pairs(List)` at the least, and the `.maxn` field is generally not present in Lua 5.1 and newer.

Comment: Thanks. I meant to call `pairs`. `maxn` is valid in 5.1 but not 5.2.